# How to call API every 10sec based on status response in angular 11?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to know how to call the API every 10secs until get success status and then after 10 second it will again start call API, i using below code for call API for every 10 secs,

now

1. **If status is Success, then api hit will stop for next 10 secs and starts after that 10 secs
   how to acheive this from angular code**

```
interval(10000).pipe(delay(1000)).subscribe(()=>{
      this.service.getLatestTrackData().subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(data);
      }, error => console.log(error))
    })
```

another method im using to call API for every 10secs, see below

```
timer(0,10000)
      .subscribe(()=>{
        this.service.getLatestTrackData().pipe(takeWhile(()=>this.alive)).subscribe(data=>{
          this.iStatus = data['status'];          
          console.log(data);
          
        })
      });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_success status_". Do you mean the status must contain a specific value that is considered success? How do you want to handle errors? Do you want to continue the polling or close it?

Comment: What about to use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` ?

Comment: @callmenikk: That would be bad idea here since each interval call would lead to a separate subscription which might be left open.

Comment: @MichaelD: we have a status column in the response. the API call iterated until the status success/error, after the status it will wait few secs and again starts its API call, this is I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way would be to introduce a multi-cast observable to start/reset/stop the timer.

1. I'd suggest to use a `BehaviorSubject` since it can start emitting straight away with the default value. Emit a number and use it to set the timer <s>and with `takeWhile` operator to close the observable</s>.
2. Use `switchMap` operator to map from the multi-cast to the timer.
3. Use `concatMap` operator to map from the timer emissions to the HTTP request.
4. Use `catchError` to capture errors and restart the timer.
5. Use `takeUntil` operator to close the subscription when the component is destroyed.

```js
POLLING_INTERVAL = 10000;                      // <-- poll every 10s
timerCtrl$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);   // <-- initially call immediately
close$ = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);            // <-- close open subscriptions

ngOnInit() {
  timerCtrl$.asObservable().pipe(
    // Update: `takeWhile` not needed - just use `takeUntil`
    // takeWhile(time => !!time)               // <-- close when `false` (0 is falsy)
    switchMap((time: number) =>
      timer(time, POLLING_INTERVAL).pipe(      // <-- start immediately, then each 10s
        concatMap(() => this.service.getLatestTrackData()),
        catchError(() => {                     // <-- start timer again on error
          this.timerCtrl$.next(POLLING_INTERVAL);
          return NEVER;                        // <-- don't forward errors  
        })
      )
    ),
    takeUntil(this.close$)
  ).subscribe({
    next: (data: any) => {
      this.iStatus = data['status'];
      if (check if status success) {
        this.timerCtrl$.next(POLLING_INTERVAL); // <-- reset polling - start again after 10s
      }

      if (some condition) {
        // Update: use the `takeUntil` here
        // this.timerCtrl$.next(0);                
        this.close$.next();                     // <-- use this to stop polling if needed
      }
    }
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.close$.next();                           // <-- close open subscriptions
}
```

Update:

1. Remote `takeWhile`
2. Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yzg8yw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Its not working, there no api call happen

Comment: @Sathishkumar: the flaw was inherent in the code. The default value of the `BehaviorSubject` was `0`, and we were checking against `0` in the `takeWhile`. I've removed the `takeWhile` and included a Stackblitz. Please check if it works now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's working as I'm expecting. Great work.